# How to add dependency within the outcomes between records in a simulation

Tags: generalized-linear-model, simulation, independence

For simplicity, consider a Generalized linear model (GLM) for the losses reported to an insurance company for damage to a building.  A standard GLM assumes the randomness of the outcomes to be independent of each other (all error terms are iid).

Which techniques can I use to incorporate dependency within the randomness of the outcomes between each record Y(i) (where Y is the reported loss and i is one row of a dataset representing a physical building)?  For example, I want to incorporate the dependency that some records share together, because their buildings are close together (ex: the randomness within the losses caused by an hurricane that hit this area will be share by multiple records at the same time, therefore, there will be dependency within the outcomes and a GLM will not catch it without any adjustment).

I want a solution that will not lose a lot of interpretability (I don't want my solution to be a black box for a non statistician).